# Remote insert over DB2 linked-server results in Table / Eager Spool in the execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, linked-server, sql-execution-plan

When I execute the SQL below I can see that all the records are being buffered in TempDb prior to the insert into the DB2 table. This kills performance with large volumes.
The execution plan suggests an Table / Eagle Spool is responsible for this behavior.

Does anyone know how to eliminate this Tempdb buffering? Linked-server settings? Hints to force the table spool not to occur? NB. There is a clustered index on RecID.

Thanks.

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(SV99TNDTA,'select OBEECD,OBAWCD from SV99TNDTA.AAOBCPP') ([OBEECD],     [OBAWCD]) 
SELECT Product_Type, 
Fnd_External_Account_Nbr 
FROM [TEST] 
WHERE RecID BETWEEN 0 AND 200
```

Exceution Plan XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

`<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.4000.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">

```
  <BatchSequence>
<Batch>
  <Statements>
    <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementId="1" StatementText="SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED &#xD;" StatementType="SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL" />
  </Statements>
  <Statements>
    <StmtSimple StatementCompId="2" StatementEstRows="88.0909" StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0174735" StatementText="&#xA;INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(SV99TNDTA,'select OBEECD,OBAWCD from SV99TNDTA.AAOBCPP') ([OBEECD], [OBAWCD]) &#xD;&#xA;SELECT Product_Type, &#xD;&#xA;Fnd_External_Account_Nbr &#xD;&#xA;FROM [TEST] &#xD;&#xA;WHERE RecID BETWEEN 0 AND 200" StatementType="INSERT" QueryHash="0xACC23A29A73BF91D" QueryPlanHash="0xC7A68418FF0DEA2D">
      <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
      <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="4" CompileCPU="4" CompileMemory="184">
        <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="8.80909E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="88.0909" LogicalOp="Remote Insert" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Remote Insert" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0174735">
          <OutputList />
          <RemoteModify RemoteSource="SV99TNDTA" RemoteObject="select OBEECD,OBAWCD from SV99TNDTA.AAOBCPP">
            <SetPredicate>
              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[MSDASQL].[OBEECD] = [Expr1006],[MSDASQL].[OBAWCD] = [Expr1007]">
                <ScalarExpressionList>
                  <ScalarOperator>
                    <MultipleAssign>
                      <Assign>
                        <ColumnReference Table="[MSDASQL]" Column="OBEECD" />
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Assign>
                      <Assign>
                        <ColumnReference Table="[MSDASQL]" Column="OBAWCD" />
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Assign>
                    </MultipleAssign>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </ScalarExpressionList>
              </ScalarOperator>
            </SetPredicate>
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="21" EstimateCPU="0.000131913" EstimateIO="0.013125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="88.0909" LogicalOp="Eager Spool" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0173854">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
              </OutputList>
              <Spool>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="21" EstimateCPU="8.80909E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="88.0909" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00412845">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <ComputeScalar>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(char(4),[WBC_PreConv].[dbo].[TEST].[Product_Type],0)">
                          <Convert DataType="char" Length="4" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="Product_Type" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Convert>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(char(10),[WBC_PreConv].[dbo].[TEST].[Fnd_External_Account_Nbr],0)">
                          <Convert DataType="char" Length="10" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="Fnd_External_Account_Nbr" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Convert>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="20" EstimateCPU="0.0002539" EstimateIO="0.00386574" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="88.0909" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00411964" TableCardinality="10000000">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="Product_Type" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="Fnd_External_Account_Nbr" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="Product_Type" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="Fnd_External_Account_Nbr" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Index="[RecID]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                        <SeekPredicates>
                          <SeekPredicateNew>
                            <SeekKeys>
                              <StartRange ScanType="GE">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="RecID" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
                                    <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </StartRange>
                              <EndRange ScanType="LE">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[WBC_PreConv]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TEST]" Column="RecID" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(200)">
                                    <Const ConstValue="(200)" />
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </EndRange>
                            </SeekKeys>
                          </SeekPredicateNew>
                        </SeekPredicates>
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </ComputeScalar>
                </RelOp>
              </Spool>
            </RelOp>
          </RemoteModify>
        </RelOp>
      </QueryPlan>
    </StmtSimple>
  </Statements>

</Batch>
  </BatchSequence>

</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Have You found a solution for this problem? I know this is a bit old topic, but I have run into same problem...